Multicollinearity (collinear predictors) checking is needed for non-linear regression (Poisson, negative binomial) and machine learning algorithms?
I am reading the book: Applied Predictive Modelling of Max Kuhn.
In part 3.5 Removing Predictors, the authors denoted that checking for Multicollinearity (collinear predictors) is important for linear regression.
However, I am confused that it is needed to examine Multicollinearity for non-linear regression (Poisson, negative binomial) and machine learning algorithms (random forest, support vector machine, k-nearest neighbours, and artificial neural network) ?
This is because multicollinearity (according to my understanding) is for linear relationships. Besides, machine learning algorithms (random forest) themselves do eliminate variables during processing.

The type of regression does not matter; the use to which result will be put does matter.
Collinearity is not really a problem if your only goal is prediction and you will not be using the parameter estimates themselves for any purpose, as you would, say, for explanation, or claiming significance, or testing hypotheses. Also, the prediction has to be for situations in the range that you have in your data.
The reason is that, when variables are colinear, two very different looking equations can yield very similar results.

thank you for your answer, it saves my day. Multicollinearity is not a focus when prediction. However, when it comes to examining causal inference, it will be important.

Multicollinearity certainly affects inference from GLMs as well.
